# performing Segue is crashing in iOS 10

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode

I have a project in swift 2.3 in Xcode 8.2 beta, This project run nicely in iOS < 10, but when I run iOS 10 this project crash with no reason preforming the segue. shows this error:

`fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`

this is the code line

```
NSOperationQueue.mainQueue().addOperationWithBlock {
     self.performSegueWithIdentifier("goToActivityDetail", sender: nil)
}
```

I don'w know whats happened, but is not even call the method

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
```

please help me! I'm desperate with the compatibility between iOS 10 and Swift 2.3 or iOS 9.3 and Swift 3

Comment: Set an exception breakpoint. What is nil?

Comment: Did you make sure you storyboard segue is set to modal presentation?

Comment: yes, is a show action

Answer (score 0):

your segue "goToActivityDetail" exist in the storyboard? and when you add the override you are setting the type of your controller? some like this:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        if segue.identifier == "goToActivityDetail"{
            let v = segue.destinationViewController as! yourControllerName
        }
    }
```

Comment: yes, the segue name is "goToActivityDetail", the problem comes before the prepareForSegue, because this method is never called

Comment: make sure that your segue si in the storyboard